# Although i am the SharePoint & global admin, i am unable to upload a .css file inside our root site collection's style library

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, administration

Although i am the SharePoint & global admin, i am unable to upload a .css file inside our Online root site collection's style library, i will get this error:-

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Did you enable "Allow users to run custom script" setting in SharePoint admin center?

SharePoint admin center > Settings > Custom Script > "Allow users to run custom script on personal sites" and "Allow users to run custom script on self-service created sites"

[image]

This change may take some time to reflect.

Comment: but i do not want to allow custom scripting on the site collection just to be able to upload the .css file